# Are "I am relaxing" and "I am relaxed" the same?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

"Relax" is a complicated verb because of its meanings.

> [re‧lax](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/relax) /rɪˈlæks/ ●●● S3 W3 AWL verb
>   1 **REST** [intransitive,
>   transitive] to rest or do something that is enjoyable, especially
>   after you have been working
>
> I just want to sit down and relax.
>   What Robyn needed was a drink to relax her.
>
> A hot bath should help
>   to relax you.
>
> 2 **BECOME CALM** [intransitive, transitive] to become quiet and calm after you have >been upset or nervous, or to make someone do this
>
> Once out of danger, he started to relax.
>
> Relax! Everything’s fine.

---

From the verb "**relax**" we have 2 adjectives "**relaxed**" & "**relaxing**"

> **[re‧laxed](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/relaxed)** /rɪˈlækst/ ●●● S2 W3 adjective
>   1 feeling calm, comfortable, and not worried or annoyed
>
> Gail was lying in the sun looking very relaxed and happy.
>
> relaxed about
>   I feel more relaxed about my career than I used to.

---

> [re‧lax‧ing](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/relaxing)
>   /rɪˈlæksɪŋ/ ●●○ adjective
>   making you feel relaxed OPP stressful
>
> a relaxing evening at home

---

So, If I say "**I am relaxing in my room**" (if we see **relax** as a verb in this case), then it means "**I am taking a rest in my room**" or "**I am getting calm in my room**".

And this is similar to "**I am relaxed in my room**" (if we see **relaxed** as an adjective in this case), it means "**I am feeling calm in my room**".

Are "**I am relaxing**" and "**I am relaxed**" the same depending on whether they are verbs or adjectives?

Comment: I can't imagine anyone saying "I am relaxed in my room". As in your dictionary examples, we say _I feel relaxed_ or that someone else _looks relaxed_.

Comment: @KateBunting "I suffer from agoraphobia. I am relaxed in my room, but very stressed when outdoors".

Comment: If I am relaxing, I assume I am relaxed. It's really quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

We do not process language by an analysis of grammatical categories.

We interpret the present participle "relaxing" as indicating a progressive sense; a process.

We interpret the perfect participle "relaxed" as indicating completion, an achieved state.

If we choose to interpret participles as adjectives for analytic purposes, they still frequently retain their verbal aspect.

> I am drinking

does not not necessarily entail that I have become inebriated.

> I am drunk

does so entail.

Now you can rightfully say that my example is comparing a compound verb and an adjective, but the fact remains that the adjective derives from a perfect participle (perfected aspect) rather than a present participle (progressive aspect) and that the adjective describes a state rather than a process.

Another way to say it is that there is no marker that invariably specifies when a participle can only be interpreted as an adjective or only be interpreted as part of a verb. There are cases where a participle is an adjective that has a partially verbal nature.

Comment: I can also say, *I am relaxing [this afternoon],* to indicate that I will be fully relaxed (i.e. there is no process/progression occurring) for a period of time.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther I cannot agree. "I am relaxing this afternoon" does not entail that I shall be completely relaxed for the entirety of some period of time. It means I shall be doing things that tend to relax me this afternoon. It may take some time for relaxation to be complete, and it may never be complete (for example if my 5 -year-old grandson arrives. To indicate completetion requires a different tense: "I shall be relaxed this afternoon after my grandson is back in the care of his parents." "Relax" can represent a state or a process.

Comment: Based on your comment and others, there seems to be two ways one can understand *relaxing*. Very interesting. I think of it more as a state than a process. When I hear, *I am relaxing*, I understand it in the same way I understand, *I am swimming. I am relaxing with a glass of wine*, is how I would express the process.  *Relaxing* can also represent a state or a process.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther I'd rather say that as a verb, it **normally** relates to a process as in "I am relaxing with a glass of wine." Notice progressive tense. However, in a perfect or past tense, it can represent the end state of that process.